# how to create a temporary table from datagridview records in sql server 2005 from c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, temp-tables

i am working on winforms in C# .Net Framework 3.5.

i have a datagridview with some records, i want to create a temporary table with data of datagridview this control is not bound to any data table or dataset. user will manually enters record in it.

Comment: Please detail what you've tried, what didn't work, etc.

Comment: i can write commands for that but i want a function provided by MS for that.

Comment: Why does the table need to be temporary? After your user enters a record, won't this be persisted somewhere else?

Comment: there is some reasonse to make a temp table on server, if there is a way to do this then please help.

Comment: I'm trying to help you but you're not providing enough information, or even suggesting that you've done any reading for yourself around the subject.

Comment: ok, i have a datagridview, contains records of city with a CheckBoxColumn, use selects cities and press a button then customers from that cities will appear in another datagridview control, 
i want to create a temp Table with selected city's reocrds, so that i can make a Select Query with that tmp Table by Join of Both Tables

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4613/discussion-between-haider-ali-and-christofr)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should be creating a `View` in SQL Server, which contains *all* records for all cities.

Then, you can create queries from your application (C#) which filter the table based on a single, selected City.

SQL Server provides caching of queries, so you will see a performance lift if the same city is queried multiple times.

The combination of your View and your query are, in essence, the 'temporary table' you are looking for. Be careful not to confuse this with SQL Server [temporary table](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/temporary-tables)s or [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx)'s.

Comment: nice way, but i want to select customers from multiple cities, then how to do this, user selects more than one city at a time.